# Spark dataframe : When does it materialize?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, aws-lake-formation

I have a spark question :

I have a job that errors out with : **403 Access Denied on S3**

The spark job basically:

1. Gets data from LF resource linked tables from Glue Catalog
2. Creates temp views
3. Runs a bunch of transformations
4. Stores the data in an external location

I get sporadic errors in step 3 where we are doing a bunch of transformations. I say sporadic, because sometimes I would get no errors and the other times it pops up on any one of the functions that exist in step 3.

Wouldnt running a spark sql select statement (and storing it as temp view) on a glue dynamic frame materialize the data within the spark session in-memory?
e.g.:

```
    df=glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog(args)
    df=df.toDF
    df.createorreplacetempview(tbl1)
    dfnew=spark.sql(select * from tbl1)
    dfnew.createorreplacetempview(tbl2)


..step3 transformations on tbl2(this is where the error happens)
```

Is my understanding correct in that tbl1 has materialized into the spark session in-memory, but tbl2 is still lazily stored?
If so, then if I run spark sql statement on tbl2 it will materialize by querying from tbl1, not the glue catalog source tables, correct?

How can I ensure in the above script the LF tables are not accessed after getting them in a dynamic frame because the upstream data is continuously updated?

Comment: `How can I ensure in the above script the LF tables are not accessed after getting them in a dynamic frame because the upstream data is continuously updated?`

is data being streamed to the source from where you are reading?

Comment: The source tables vary in cadence. Some are continuously updated and some are updated using cron job schedules. The output is the result of a bunch of joins that is first cached, then added to temp view, and then written to a location in a snappy parquet. Caching is expensive so Id rather not do that. Ill update the question with further info on the transformation and more error details

Answer (score 3):

The understanding that you have of spark SQL views is not correct.

`Spark SQL` views are lazily evaluated and don't really materialize until you call an action. In fact, **NONE** of the lazily evaluated parts (also called transformations in Spark technical terms) are materialized until and unless you call an action.

All it does is create a DAG in the backend with all the transformations you have done so far and materialize all that when you call an action.

```py
df.createorreplacetempview(tbl1) #lazily-evaluated
dfnew=spark.sql(select * from tbl1) #lazily-evaluated
dfnew.createorreplacetempview(tbl2) #lazily-evaluated
dfnew.show() #Action call --> materilaizes all the transformations done so far.
```

The error you are getting is most likely because of the p*ermissions while reading or writing into a particular S3 location.*

I hope this answers your first half of the question. It can be explained better if you can share what is happening in the transformation or if you are using any action during those transformations or the best way is to share the `stacktrace` of the error to get more definitive answer.

Also if you are using `Spark 3.0 or higher` you can materialize your transformations by using `noop` write format.

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").format("noop").save()
```

You can simply specify it as the `write` format and it will materialize the query and execute all the transformations but it will not write the result anywhere.

Comment: I figured the same thing, so I added the dfnew.count() action in there, and after getting counts, it threw the same error when I tried creating a table. Seems to happen at:
1. spark sql for caching
2. spark sql for CREATE TABLE <table> USiNG PARQUET LOCATION <path> AS <select query using temp view>

Seems like the LF table location is getting updated during the code execution, which is why I wanted to know if the data was being materialized or else if there is an option to update/refresh the metadata on failure(without having to parse the query for table names)?

Comment: Two things to mention here is: 
1. `.cache()` is a transformation so until and unless you are not calling any action it's not gonna cache the dataframe into memory.
2. I am not sure where are you trying to create table using create command in `spark.sql` but if you want to create a table the best way to do it in spark is `.saveAsTable` which will materialize the entire table but as you mentioned before that you are creating a temp table, using `createOrReplaceTempView` should be enough to create a temp table.